# Cannot select check boxes of an Ext checkbox model grid panel

Tags: extjs, checkbox, grid

I have an extjs (ExtJS 3) grid panel which is loaded from postgresql database using JsonStore. This is my Json store:

```
var dropPickGridStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
fields : [ {
    name : 'locationName'
}, {
    name : 'city'
}, {
    name : 'addr'
}, {
    name : 'estimatedTime'
} ],
root : 'dropPickLoc',
idProperty : 'locationName',
//autoDestroy : true,
autoLoad : true,

proxy : new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
    url : "http://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + projectName + "/"
            + "PendingDropPicks"

}),
reader : {
    type : 'json',
    root : 'dropPickLoc'
},
});
```

This my grid panel:

```
var selectModel = new Ext.grid.CheckboxSelectionModel();
/*selectModel : Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
checkOnly: true,
mode: 'MULTI'
});*/
var drop_pick_grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
store : dropPickGridStore,
cm : new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([ selectModel, {
    sortable : true,
    header : "Drop/Pick Loc",
    dataIndex : 'locationName',
    width : 170
}, {
    header : "Town/City",
    sortable : true,
    dataIndex : 'city',
    width : 120
}, {
    header : "Address",
    sortable : true,
    dataIndex : 'addr',
    width : 170
}, {
    header : "EST.Un/Load Time",
    sortable : true,
    dataIndex : 'estimatedTime',
    width : 100
} ]),
sm : selectModel,
//width : 570,
//height : 390,
autoHeight : true,
autoWidth : true,
frame : true,
iconCls : 'icon-grid'
});
```

The gris is loaded successfully. But There is a problem. I can only check the header row checkbox. I cannot select any of row. It should has the capability of selecting individual row and it should also can select all rows by clicking header checkbox. What's wrong with my code?

Can anyone please be so kind enough to explain what's going wrong with my codes and how should I fix it?

Thank You

Comment: `idProperty` should be in `reader` property!

Comment: Thanx for your reply. But it's not working

Comment: which browser you are facing the issue? have you tried with multiple browsers?

Comment: I am using firefox.i should use it